# Between models, how do I determine what variables to drop?

Tags: regression

looking to clear up some of my knowledge gaps.

Suppose given a dataset, and I am looking to compare the test MSE between different model implementations. For example, between a logistic regression and LDA, I am looking to compare the performance between these 2 approaches based on their test error.

Suppose that I wish to drop variables, is there a way to determine what variables to drop for these 2 models?

I understand that there are pvalues associated with logistic regression for each predictor. However, if I were to drop variables based on their significance from a logistic regression, would it make sense to use whatever variables that were not dropped to form a LDA model?

Any help to bridge these knowledge gaps would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you wish to drop variables?